# **Python selenium error** :Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to fetch the tweets from a twitter url. But when I execute the code, the following error occurs some of the times :

```
StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.89)
```

The error points to this line :

```
---> 18         print(tweet.text)
```

This is the corresponding code :

```py
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import csv

browser = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/Suraj/Desktop/twitter/chromedriver')
hashtag = 'Candles4SSR'
url = 'https://twitter.com/hashtag/'+hashtag+'?src=hashtag_click'
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(1)
body = browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body')

tweet_contents = []
for _ in range(5):
    tweets = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("[data-testid=\"tweet\"]")
    
    for tweet in tweets:
        print(tweet.text)
        tweet_contents += [tweet.text]
    body.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
    time.sleep(0.4)
```

Any help or suggestions would be really appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use Twitter's API (e.g. [Tweepy](https://www.tweepy.org/), [Twython](https://stackabuse.com/accessing-the-twitter-api-with-python/) or [python-twitter](https://github.com/bear/python-twitter)) itself? `Selenium` is a little tricky and it's useful when scraping is the only way to access the data you want.

Comment: @RezaBehzadpour I have requested access, but it may take days for them to grant permission or they may not even grant it.

Comment: Okay, I see. Complex web applications create and destroy objects on the fly. You can use this [link](https://github.com/Zeeshanahmad4/Tweets-Scraper-twitter-Selenium) for inspiration on how to fetch tweets from Twitter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web element `tweets` found before the for loop becomes inaccessible inside the for loop at the end for some reason.

So I tried initiating `tweets` again inside the for loop and it works now. It seems to be a temporary fix, but works.

The last block of my code now :

```py
tweet_contents = []
for _ in range(5):
    tweets = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("[data-testid=\"tweet\"]")
    time.sleep(1)
    for tweet in tweets:
        print(tweet.text)
        tweet_contents += [tweet.text]
        tweets = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("[data-testid=\"tweet\"]") # initialising tweets variable again inside for loop
    body.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
    time.sleep(0.4)

tweet_contents = sorted(set(tweet_contents), key=tweet_contents.index) # To remove duplicates, whilst preserving the order of tweets
```

Comment: Changed the `for _ in range(5)` to a `while` loop to terminate loop when 30 tweets are scraped, but it won't work :(

Answer (score 3):

seems like it takes the tweets to load more than 0.4 seconds

i copy pasted the code with changing the sleep time from 0.4 to 2 seconds and it worked fine.

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/Suraj/Desktop/twitter/chromedriver')
hashtag = 'Candles4SSR'
url = 'https://twitter.com/hashtag/' + hashtag + '?src=hashtag_click'
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(1)
body = browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body')

tweet_contents = []
for _ in range(5):
    tweets = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("[data-testid=\"tweet\"]")

    for tweet in tweets:
        print(tweet.text)
        tweet_contents += [tweet.text]
    body.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
    time.sleep(2)
```

if you see it works on your env consider increasing the sleep time from 0.4 to some higher number.

another option is to use a retry mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Stale element exception means Web element is there on page but driver instance could not interact with that element.

```
There  are 2 ways to overcome this stale element issue 
1.Using refresh method in selenium (driver.navigate().refresh();)
2.Using for loop try to looping until that element is click
```

Comment: use 

for tweet in tweets:
driver.navigate().refresh();
        print(tweet.text)